# Need to conduct and INDEX and MATCH function in r

Tags: r

I am at a bit of a loss on how to both approach this problem and ask the question. I basically want to conduct an `INDEX` and `MATCH` function in R and then multiply two numbers.

Here is an example. I have two tables with different dimensions. Note the differences in both row and columns.

```
MASS = data.frame(taxa = c("a","b","c"), s1 = c(1,1,1), s2 = c(2,2,2), s3 = c(3,3,3))

DATA = data.frame(taxa = c("b","c"), s1 = c(1,0), s3 = c(4,6))
```

I need to multiple the cells from the DATA table with the corresponding cells in the MASS table (e.g., `DATA cell "b:s3" * MASS cell "b:s3"`) and output the results to a new table. Below is the desired result.

```
RESULT = data.frame(taxa = c("b","c"), s1 = c(1,0), s3 = c(12,18))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a strategy using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

merge(gather(MASS, obs, val1, -taxa), gather(DATA, obs, val2, -taxa)) %>%   
    mutate(val=val1*val2) %>% 
    select(taxa,obs,val) %>% 
    spread(obs, val)
```

which returns

```
  taxa s1 s3
1    b  1 12
2    c  0 18
```

We use `gather()` on the two input data.frames to reshape them to the long format, then we can merge them to we get the overlapping taxa/observations. Then we perfrom the transformation, and finally we reshape back to wide format.